# Eclipse: Compiler defines and Code highlighting

Tags: c, eclipse, symbols, code-editor

I have an existing C-Project with a pre-written Makefile. I imported the whole thing as a Makefile-Project into Eclipse and it is working fine so far - meaning I can navigate through the code with eclipse and I can build it without problems.

Now I added some Compiler Symbols like `NO_ASM`to my makefile and updated the code at some points with the according lines of

```
#ifdef NO_ASM
// Code
#endif
```

This code is greyed out by my Code-Editor. Now I added the Symbol `NO_ASM` to 
`Properties/C/C++ General/Paths and Symbols` and rebuilt the indexer - but the according code is still grey. Is there any way to solve this?

Comment: I have the same problem here; did you find a solution?

Comment: I have the same problem in ARM DS5 which is based on Eclipse Luna. In Eclipse Kepler using GNU ARM GCC cross compiler it is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you added it to all configurations? in all Languages?

You can Try Freshen all files option.

A temporal workaround can something like this:

```
#ifndef NO_ASM
    #define NO_ASM
#endif
```